# многопотоковая закачка страниц

Tags: java, многопоточность, httpclient

Требуется:

1. Авторизоваться на сайте;
2. Определить количество страниц с которых будем скачивать информацию (отправляем get запрос, получаем ответ в котором ссылки на страницы. Ссылки имеют одинаковый формат, в конце строки в параметре посто меняется номер страницы);
3. Не перелогиниваясь нужно скачать информацию с различных страниц в несколько потоков под своим аккаунтом. Количество потоков требуется указать самостоятельно.

Делаю примерно так(некоторые параметры отсутствуют)

```
public class Downloader {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Downloader.class);
    private String domainLink;
    private String sourceHtmlPage;

    ExecutorService executorService;
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient;

    private HttpEntity entity = null;
    private HttpResponse response;
    private HttpGet httpget;
    Map<String, String> pagesNamesAndKeys;

    public Downloader() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .setMaxConnPerRoute(1000)
            .setMaxConnTotal(1000)
            .build();

        httpClient.start();
        if (autorizateOnServer()) {
            getpageList();
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new DaemonThreadFactory());
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> pageKeyAndName : pagesNamesAndKeys.entrySet()) {
            executorService.submit(new PageInfo( httpClient, pageKeyAndName.getKey()));
            }

        LOGGER.info("Added all threads into executor");
        LOGGER.info(executorService.toString());
        while (((ThreadPoolExecutor)executorService).getActiveCount() > 0) {
            System.out.print("#");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        LOGGER.info("Complete");
        } else {
        httpClient.close();
        }
    //            logout(logoutLink);
    }

    private boolean autorizateOnServer() {

        String urlForLogin = "http://pagewithinfo.com/webmaster.php";
        Boolean loginIsTrue = false;
        String tempLocationHeader;
        HttpPost httpPost;
        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        String userName = "myLogin";
        String password = "pass";

        httpPost = new HttpPost(urlForLogin);
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(formFieldUser, userName));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(formFieldPassword, password));

        try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
        Future<HttpResponse> future = httpClient.execute(httpPost, null);
        response = future.get();
        entity = response.getEntity();

        String sourceHttpPage = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        tempLocationHeader = String.valueOf(response.getFirstHeader("Location"));

        if (tempLocationHeader.equals("Location: webmaster.php")) {
            LOGGER.info(tempLocationHeader);
            loginIsTrue = true;
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("pagewithinfo login false");
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.info(urlForLogin + " - Не удалось залогиниться :( Exception");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return loginIsTrue;
    }

    private void getpageList() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        httpget = new HttpGet("http://pagewithinfo.com/webmaster.php?content=stat");
        Future<HttpResponse> future = httpClient.execute(httpget, null);
        response = future.get();
        entity = response.getEntity();

        String sourseHttpPage = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sourseHttpPage);
        Element form = doc.select("select[name=\"filter_idproduct\"]").first();
        Elements idProducts = form.getElementsByTag("option");
        String pageid;
        String pageName;
        pagesNamesAndKeys = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (Element idProduct : idProducts) {
        pageid = idProduct.attr("value");
        pageName = idProduct.text();
        if (!pageid.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pageid.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            pagesNamesAndKeys.put(pageid, pageName);
            //добавить сайт в DB
        }
        }
    }

    private  void logout(String link) throws IOException {
    //        httpget.setURI(URI.create(link));
    //        httpСlient.execute(httpget);
    //        LOGGER.info("Logout pagewithinfo");
    }
}
```

При этом закачка всегда идет в один поток, а не в 10 как в настройках. Все потоки почему-то в состоянии wait всегда, а потом вообще закрываются.
Нужно именно через Executor (или похожий вариант), так как потоки постоянно могут добавляться, если залогинется на другой сайт и запустить скачивание инфы со страниц.

Как реализовать данную задачу?

**Обновление**

Спасибо за наводку. До этого всё было правильно у меня сделано, потом посмотрел в сторону `CloseableHttpAsyncClient`, так как не знал, что по умолчанию качает в 2 потока, нужно увеличить данное значение `setDefaultMaxPerRoute()`.

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    cm.setMaxTotal(50);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50);
    httpСlient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .build();
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы чуть чуть не дочитали матчасть. для httpclient есть [PoolingClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html).

[Пример](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java), который ответит на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Плюсовать кармы не хватает, ответ 100% в точку.Спасибо.